# Checkbox returns true in edge browser where as chrome works as expected

Tags: angular, checkbox

Check box issue in Edge browser. 
When I console.log(), get True in edge where as false in chrome

```
<input type="checkbox" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" 
class="setup- checkbox"id="addRoleDeleteChkBox" 
[(ngModel)]="userRoleAll.isDeleteChecked"
(click)="selectAllRoles('delete')">
```

It works well in chrome as expected but not in edge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use change instead of click

```
<input type="checkbox" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" 
class="setup- checkbox"id="addRoleDeleteChkBox" 
[(ngModel)]="userRoleAll.isDeleteChecked"
(change)="selectAllRoles('delete')">
```

Comment: @nishanth please support the answer if its working in your case